# How to detect correct button when page is redirected for HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, yii

I have a form (form 1) which I submit and show data below form 1...when I click on the `proceed` button present in the data I show below, I show a new form with `submit` button and a `go back` button....

When user clicks, `go back` I would like to show the submitted form (form 1) with submitted i.e. data below... to store data in session and retreive it later is ok but the issue is `HTTP_REFERER` would return the same url, on `go back` or `submit` button (as once data submitted I redirect page back to `form 1`)

Can anyone direct me on how to use this system wisely while `submitting data` or `go back` button?

One option I found out as i write this:
pass an argument to function setting it default to `0` and change it to `1` only when `Go Back` is clicked....

Is this the only (or best) way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

One option I found out as i write this: 
pass an argument to function setting it default to 0 and change it to 1 only when Go Back is clicked.

well, that's what i have used and would appreciate better responses on the same.